# React native not recognizing finally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Finally keyword is undefined on a classic es6 helloworld fetch example.

```
let isLoading = true;

fetch("https://jsfiddle.net").then(function(response) {
    var contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
    if(contentType && contentType.includes("application/json")) {
      return response.json();
    }
    throw new TypeError("Oops, we haven't got JSON!");
  })
  .then(function(json) { /* process your JSON further */ })
  .catch(function(error) { console.error(error); /* this line can also throw, e.g. when console = {} */ })
  .finally(function() { isLoading = false; console.log("done")});
```

Comment: React native or reactjs? What's the environment this is being run on?

Comment: react native app, uses typescript, mac, ihave changed es2015 to es2018 but still same, should i add any preset on babel or smth

Comment: iOS, Android, web?

Comment: android is that matters

Comment: Which android version? Android 8+ supports finally just fine https://caniuse.com/#feat=promise-finally

Comment: i am on 8 , its mobile app not browser app

Comment: Finally is not supported on Android 1.0. You will need to use a library to "polyfill" instead. Why are you supporting an android version that's over 10 years old? (Or are you not? I saw the comment was edited)

Comment: polyfill is required  for rn mobile app? yes yes android 8 but it gives error on finally and the device is emulator

Comment: Depends if the target device supports the feature you want. We've probably gone down the wrong rabbit hole anyway as I don't think you are using Android 1.0

Comment: i am using android 8 device emulator

Comment: @toyegej962 it's working fine for me using `RN 0.61` on Android 10 emulator. Here is the [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/rb3z9c). Which version of RN are you using and how did you create your project app?

Comment: @evolutionxbox [this](https://caniuse.com/#feat=promise-finally) page refers about **Android Webview** and **NOT** React Native, it has nothing to do with how or what RN JS engine supports.